# Inverse Modulo for an Integer

Tags: c#, math, integer, modulo

I am trying to code this in C# but I have problems finding an algorithm to do that.
The goal is to code a function which takes an integer as Parameter and returns an Integerarray (returns 2 integers).

This function should find a valid modulo calculation for the input number which will have as result (reminder) the same number as the input.

For example my Input is the number 5.
Now a valid modulo calculation should be found of which the result is 5.
For example 12 % 7 = 5.
So the function should return 12 and 7.
How can I find the modulo and the divider which will have the same result as the input number?
I cannot show any code because I don't know how I should start of with coding that. 
Would be cool of someone can help me out.

Comment: The problem is somewhat ill-defined, as for a nonnegative input `a`, the pair `(a,a+1)` trivially solves the equation `a = a % a+1`, what is probably not what is actually meant.

Comment: You do realise that there's not going to be just one valid answer, do you?

Comment: Now I'm not very good at math but aren't there infinite possiblities? Don't you need to narrow them with further conditions?

Comment: Yes, there are actuall infinite possibilities, this is why I pointed out that possibly the question fails to express the actually desired behaviour.

Comment: I am not so good in Matt either, but if there are inifine possibilities, then just choose randomly one. If possible both numbers should be integers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. think the problem should be:

   - `x%y=z`
   - **a)** where `x,z` are knowns `y` is unknown
   - instead of
   - **b)** where `z` is known and `x,y` are unknowns as stated in OP text
2. anyway for booth cases

   - the easiest but also the slowest way to compute it is brute-force attack

example **a)**:

```
const int max=1024; // some solution constraint ...
int imod(int x,int z)
 {
 if (z==0) return x; // if no remainder then solution is any multiple of x
 for (int y=z+1;y<max;y++) if (x%y==z) return y;
 return 0; // no solution found
 }
```

- y can be anything sufficing condition `y > z`
- that is why start with z+1

example **b)**:

```
void imod(int &x,int &y,int z)
 {
 // this is not brute-force because the solution is trivial from the conditions stated in OP
 x=z;
 y=z+1;
 }
```

- no comment needed (all is explained in the comments to your question)

[notes]

- code is in C++ so modify it to your language ...
- if you need to corelate more numbers to find originally used modulo (crack some code)
- then remember all the solutions and choose one common for all numbers
- or check all the numbers at once and use only solutions satisfying all the numbers at once
- if you have access to original modulo then you can pass incresing numbers to it until it cut off the result value in that case your `x>=y` so you can recursively find the match in O(log(N)) instead of O(N)...

Comment: Thanks for your detailed reply helped me a lot to understand the modulo better;)

Answer (score 0):

Step 1. Choose a number, this will be your first output number.  Step 2 subtract the input from that number, that will be your other output number

Comment: What do you mean by choose a number? A random one? Are there some requirements for the range like can this number also be 0 or less than 0?

Comment: Well the chosen number cannot be `0`, as division by zero usually is not defined. The answer can be rephrased as follows. Let `a` be the input, choose `b` such that `b>a`, then `a=b%(b-a)`, so return `(b,b-a)`.